# database id based referencing

Tags: database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table called `branch` which will store the details of a branch office like its manager, location etc. The fields are:

```
branch_id
branch_manager
branch_location
```

Data in this table would look like:

```
1    Mr. John Doe      Manhattan
2    Miss. Jane Doe    Utah
3    Mr. Random Guy    Somewhere
```

There is another table called `services` which stores all service details. The fields are:

```
service_id
service_name
```

Data would be like:

```
1   New Sales
2   After-Sales Support
3   Replacement
4   Exchange Offer
```

Now I want to store the services available in each branch. Normally I guess it is done by creating a new table called `branch_services` which will contain `branch_id` and `service_id`. So if I have following record in `branch_services`

```
branch-id  service-id
1          2
1          3
2          1
```

This means that the Manhattan branch does After-Sales Support and Replacement, while the Utah branch does only New Sales.

Now my question is - instead of having this `branch_services` table, what if I stored a comma separated list of services in the branch table itself?

```
1    Mr. John Doe      Manhattan    2,3
2    Miss. Jane Doe    Utah         1
3    Mr. Random Guy    Somewhere
```

What are the main arguments against this? Is it that queries would be more difficult/slower to execute (e.g. if I wanted to see which all branches did a particular service)? Is there any advantage by structuring it comma separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in the way that you prefer (i.e. you can have your text fields in Cyrillic alphabet) but you have also to consider what you want to do with your data (i.e. you want to store English words and you and your colleagues don't know Cyrillic alphabet).

If you are working with a relational database, I suspect you are going to use SQL. Now I can write a query like:

```
select b.branch_location,
       s.service_name
  from branch b
inner join branch_services b_s 
        on b.branch_id = b_s.branch_id
inner join services s
        on b_s.service_id = s.service_id
```

To obtain:

```
branch_location service_name 
Manhattan       After-Sales Support 
Manhattan       Replacement 
Utah            New Sales
```

Because SQL is designed to query a RDMS and in our case the relationship is between the content of the columns `branch_id` in `branch` and `branch_services` (or service_id in `branch_services` and `services`).

Of course, we can understand that `2,3` mean the same than `2` and `3` in two different rows, but SQL is not able to understand that. [Actually what we do is to split the `2,3` string in two values and associate each of them to a row in the `services` tables. Not that simple to do it in pure SQL.]

Your question is about performance, before to get there the real question is "Can I query such kind of structure with SQL?" Yes and no.

If to get a list of branches and services, like my query above, can be quite complicated, to get the branch that does a specific service is still doable, after all if need to check who does `New Sales` you need only to see if in your services list there is a 1, but exclude all 10, 11, 12 and so on. Uhm... not that straight forward.

What I'm trying to show you is that the three tables structure is more flexible, if you need to use it with SQL and not with a human brain. Unfortunately computers are not yet that smart.

So:

Is it possible to store data comma-separated in a column? **Yes**.

Is a good idea? Usually **No** if you want to use it in a relationship with another table.

Usually? If they need just to expose the long comma-separated string, then yes.

Comment: I got only one answer for this question, but it was the best! thanks a lot!!

Comment: I tried my best, relational databases sometimes follow a defiant logic. Keep the design and your queries simple as much as you can